# Should I recompile the full Java solution during migration from Oracle JDK to Amazon Corretto

Tags: java, corretto

The initial requirement is to support Amazon Corretto. I have a lot of jar's which are already built by Oracle JDK.

Amazon Corretto is certified using the Java Technical Compatibility Kit (TCK), and It meets the Java SE standard, so should I re-compile all these jars using different JDK (Amazon Corretto 8 in this case)? Does it makes sence?

Comment: Why rebuild them unless you've identified a specific problem?

Comment: @DaveNewton, That was actually my question, are there any possible underwater rocks I can met by running jar built by Oracle JDK on Amazon Corretto JRE.

Comment: Sure, there's always risk when changing platforms. Is it a *large* risk? I doubt it; that's why we have tests. Corretto is just another OpenJDK.

Comment: So, are you assume there is no need to recompile solution on Amazon Corretto instead of Oracle JDK? What about commercial usage, is there any restrictions to build my solution by Oracle JDK 8 and execute on Amazon Corretto 8 JRE?

Comment: I *assume* there is no need to recompile. I don't *know* there is no need to recompile. IANAL: I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no need to recompile your Java files into bytecode (class files) when switching between Oracle JDK or Open JDK and Amazon Corretto.  If you're switching to a newer JDK then that might be worth investigating, but otherwise Amazon's Corretto is 100% compatible with Oracle and Open JDK.

The Amazon Corretto FAQ has more info:  https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/faqs/